# How to make a different color lines in the TextBox WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

how to make different color lines in TextBox WPF?

It is necessary that on the first line of text is red, the second green ...

It is desirable to answer with an example.

Thanks for the replies =)

I need to do so:

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of what you have tried so far? In general you can set the text color through the Foreground property of the Textbox.

Comment: Sorry. I updated my question, I think so clearly.

Comment: `TextBox` does not support what you need, you should use `RichTextBox`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `RichTextBox`to implement this.

```
<RichTextBox>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph Foreground="Red">Red</Paragraph>
        <Paragraph Foreground="Green">Green</Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: No, no, no ... I need to use only one TextBox

Comment: I misunderstood your question sorry. I modify the code. Please check it out to see if meeting your requirements.